# Multiple rows from one row based on data in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset like this:

| Author | Title | ISBN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AuthorA | Title1 | 9788799185610; 879918561X |
| AuthorB | Title2 | 9781526615893; 1526615894; 9781526615879; 1526615878 |

I would like to get data looking like this

| Author | Title | ISBN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Author A | Title1 | 9788799185610 |
| Author A | Title1 | 879918561X |
| AuthorB | Title2 | 9781526615893 |
| AuthorB | Title2 | 1526615894 |
| AuthorB | Title2 | 9781526615879 |
| AuthorB | Title2 | 1526615878 |

Anyone that can help me with what might do the trick?

Note: ISBN can contain both numbers and letters and the different numbers are separated in the dataset with ;